# Include CSS in a single JS file from Vite, for use in single-spa

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rollup, vite, single-spa

I'm prototyping a single-spa which contains Vue apps built with Vite, following the very helpful [example](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-vite/).

I've got `vite build` to generate a single js file that single-spa can point to, and that's being loaded fine.

However `vite build` always separates out the CSS into a separate CSS file. Ideally for use in single-spa it would be bundled within the same JS file. What's the optimal way to do this?

I *can* load this using the single-spa-css package, but I was expecting some rollup or `vite.config.js` option to achieve this.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need a single CSS file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bundle JS and CSS into single file with Vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67781170/bundle-js-and-css-into-single-file-with-vite)

Comment: The answer on that thread seems to relate to a Svelte plugin for vite - I'm using Vue, but a plugin like that is indeed what I'm after.