# how to bundle my images and svg with my js code in vite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, vite

I'm trying to bundle my whole js and css and images into a single file in vite and already, based on this question:[Bundle JS and CSS into single file with Vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67781170/bundle-js-and-css-into-single-file-with-vite)
, I've figured out how to bundle my css and js together but still don't know how to bundle my images into that file, so I wonder how I can pull this task off?

edit:

first I installed:

```
npm install @rollup/plugin-image --save-dev
```

this is what I have in my `vite.config.js` file(I've tried this without input and still it didn't work):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from "vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js";
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [react(), cssInjectedByJsPlugin(), image()],
input: 'src/main.jsx',
build: {

rollupOptions: {
  output: {
    manualChunks: undefined,
  },
},
},
})
```

after executing `npm run build`, only js and css files get bundled to eachother and I have svg as separate files.

this is my file hierarchy:

```
project
|
|_ _  src
       |
       |_ _App.jsx
       |_ _ App2.jsx
       |_ _ main.jsx
       |_ _ index.css
       |_ _ App.css
       |_ _ image1.svg
       |_ _ image2.svg
```

and this is what I get after running npm run build:

```
project
|
|_ _  src
|      |
|      |_ _App.jsx
|      |_ _ App2.jsx
|      |_ _ main.jsx
|      |_ _ index.css
|      |_ _ App.css
|      |_ _ image1.svg
|      |_ _ image2.svg
|
|_ _ dist
      |
      |_ _bundle.js(bundle of all my js and css files)
      |_ _ svg1.svg
      |_ _ svg2.svg
```

note: these svg1 and svg2 are representing image1.svg and image2.svg before bundle.

note2: all css and js files in `src` get imported to `main.jsx`.

so basically I don't get any error, just the process is like before and my bundle only includes javascript and css files and not my images.

Comment: look [here](https://github.com/vitejs/awesome-vite?tab=readme-ov-file#compatible-with-vite)

Comment: I checked that, I found this might be https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/image helpful, but it was talking about something rollup config file and calling it via cli which I couldn't get it and was ambiguous.@JaromandaX

Comment: there's a link to documentation about rollup plugin compatibility - read that, with the understanding that the plugin you've found IS compatible with vite, therefore you can use it just like it was a vite plugin (at least, that is my understanding)

Comment: I implemented that but it didn't work.@JaromandaX

Comment: perhaps you *did it wrong™* - since you haven't shown what you've done, it's hard to say. Also *it didn't work* doesn't convey any useful information. What happened? Nothing at all? Some error messages? A crack in the space-time continuum?

Comment: no answer man?@JaromandaX